# verify a method is called only once with a given parameter with Junit 5

Tags: junit5

I want to ensure that my test calls the `userService.find(userName)` only with the expected `aTestName` and only once. Currently, I am achieving this by the following code. Is there a way to combine the two `BDDMockito.then...` in one?

```
String aTestName = "aTestName";
BDDMockito.then(userService).should(times(1)).findByName(any());
BDDMockito.then(userService).should(times(1)).findByName(aTestName);
```

Comment: That should work without verifying `any()` part.

Comment: If I remove my first .then() with .findByName(any()). Then I could call the finByName more than once with different argument, ie userService.findByName("aTestName"); userService.findByName(null); And I want to prevent that I call ie. .findByName(user.addressStreet())

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is `only()`. So like:

```
BDDMockito.then(userService).should(only()).findByName(aTestName);
```